# Codeigniter spaces in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a method which returns all jobs by category.
The problem it's when i have spaces in the category name. How could I access those results?

for ex if i access `http://localhost/management_system/Job/get_jobs_by_cat/Architecture` it will return all the jobs from the `Architecture` category.

But when i try to access the category `Information Technology` I can't do it while I have `spaces` into the url, so I've tried with `_ -` and i didn't get any response.

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: You can use rawurlencode http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: Slugify category name on insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would likely want to use [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode the url parameters in the controller function processing this logic.  In your controller, do something like this:

```
$jobCat = urldecode($this->uri->segment(4));
```

Then, you would pass `$jobCat` to your model.

Here are some other Stack Overflow links that might help your cause.

> [How to pass parameters with space to controller from URL in
>   codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939359/how-to-pass-parameters-with-space-to-controller-from-url-in-codeigniter)
>
> [Php - Codeigniter url spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599516/php-codeigniter-url-spaces)
>
> [what is the use of $this->uri->segment(3) in codeigniter
>   pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293892/what-is-the-use-of-this-uri-segment3-in-codeigniter-pagination)

Comment: With urlencode I have some issues when i have to encode the categories with / in the name, ex `Accounting / Finance` becomes `Accounting+%2F+Finance` which gives me the fallowing error Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: @TerchilăMarian the error is likely because it is a forward slash (/).  The forward slash makes it think there is another segment in the URL.  You might need to replace that in the output somehow.

Comment: So if i wanna make it i have to replace the `/` with something else?
That's the only way?

Comment: @TerchilăMarian you might be about to adjust the route in `routes.php` or .htaccess file to get the desired result without replacing anything.

Comment: [This article might help your cause a bit, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607202/codeigniter-url-segments-contaning-leading-slash)

Comment: If i replace the `/` with an `,` it will solve the problem?

Comment: It could, but you would have to remember to do a replace that comma before you sent it to your model.  so, you would do both a string replace and a urldecode before passing it off to your model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode `Information Technology`.

```
$category = 'Information Technology';
$encodedCategory = rawurlencode($category);
$url = 'http://localhost/management_system/Job/get_jobs_by_cat/' . $encodedCategory;

echo $url;
// http://localhost/management_system/Job/get_jobs_by_cat/Information%20Technology
```

Comment: With urlencode I have some issues when i have to encode the categories with / in the name, ex Accounting / Finance becomes Accounting+%2F+Finance which gives me the fallowing error Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.